# binding a parameter that's not always set

Tags: php, sql

**index.php**

```
<a href="index.php?type=potato"><div>click here to select only potato</div></a>
$typesql = $_GET['type'];
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?");
$results->bind_param("s", $typesql);
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($name, $type);
```

the above query runs by default showing all types of vegetables when index.php is loaded, then I decided to add a button which alters the results to show only potato, now when type is not in the url it no longer shows all vegetables because WHERE type = ? is not set, how to set the default type to be all types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check whether the GET parameter is blank or not, so try this

```
<a href="index.php?type=potato"><div>click here to select only potato</div></a>
    $typesql = $_GET['type'];
    if($typesql){
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?");
    $results->bind_param("s", $typesql);
    }
    else {
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists");
    }

    $results->execute();
    $results->bind_result($name, $type);
```

Comment: Please do not provide 'code-only' answers. Explain to the OP (and possible future users) what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `type` parameter is set and change your query according to that.

Something like this (not tested):

```
if (!empty($_GET['type'])) {
    $typesql = $_GET['type'];
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?");
    $results->bind_param("s", $typesql);
} else {
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists");
}
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($name, $type);
```